# Connection on isomorphic principal bundle

Tags: fiber-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

I’m trying to find a natural induced connection $1$-form on the isomorphic principal bundle, more explicitly, given a principal bundle isomorphism $(P:P_1\rightarrow P_2$, $\Phi:G\rightarrow H)$ between principal bundles $G\rightarrow P_1\rightarrow M$ and $H\rightarrow P_2\rightarrow M$ on the same base manifold, and a connection $1$-form $A$ on $P_1$, then how to construct a natural connection $1$-form on $P_2$ by using the isomorphism $P$? I have tried to use the pull back construction, but realized that the induced diffeomorphism from $P$ is trivial, and hence will not work. Any suggestions? Perhaps you can give the correct formula, and I will try to prove it by myself, I just can’t see the construction... Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking: If $P$ is an isomorphism of principal bundles, then the induced $1$-form on $P_{2}$ should be $(P^{-1})^{*}A$. Is that what you mean by "the pull back construction"? Whether or no, the induced connection is bound to look "exactly like $A$" since, in an abstract sense, it _is_ exactly $A$. Is that what you mean by "the induced diffeomorphism from $P$ is trivial"...?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, by the pull-back construction, I really mean the pull-back connection on the pull-back bundle, and now I realize this doesn’t make sense at all... So basically, we can just pull-back the connection $1$-form in the sense of differential forms to get a connection on the isomorphic bundle? @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: Ah, right. :) Yes, if $P$ is a principal bundle isomorphism, then a connection on one bundle induces a connection on the other by pulling back the connection form by $P^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have just finished prove it. @AndrewD.Hwang